# How to find average of something like this in php $a = 01:04:06:02:55:28 $b = 03:04:06:02:54:34?

Tags: php, datetime

```
$a = 01:04:06:02:55:28
$b = 03:04:06:02:54:34
//format("%Y:%M:%D:%H:%I:%S")
```

I would like to find average of these two.

In this case $a is time taken to finish task 1 and $b is time taken to finish task 2, Now I would like to know average time taken by the person to complete two tasks.

Comment: What does `average` mean to you?

Comment: you mean you want to get the difference?

Comment: Weird datetime format.

Comment: So what should the "Average" be in this case? Do you mean the mid-point between the two date/times?

Comment: Your datetime format is very strange. How did you get that in the first place?

Comment: As noted above, it is a strange format for a time duration. Notice that there is some ambiguity: month could have 30 days or 31, or even 28 or 29. Year could be 365 or 366. If possible, you'd better code the duration in seconds (or the unit that best fits your case). If this format is mandatory, then you'd better implement the calculation yourself to avoid such ambiguity, in case you are assuming a specific duration for years and months.

Comment: Hello Airos, that is not date and time format, i.e difference between two point of times, simply consider it as $a - 01:04:06:02:55:28 = one year 4 months 6 days 2 hours 55 minutes and 28 seconds.

Comment: I understood that. My point remains though. 1 month could be 30 days or 31 days. You need to assume what the duration of "year", "month" are in your case (usually, year=365 days and month=30 days). However, if using the API methods, Datetime assumes the gregorian calendar. It's not the same 1 year 1 month 1 day than the 1st of January of year 1. ;-)

Comment: you are right airos, but you are one step behind, i calculated that now i want $a+$b/2

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the mean of the two timestamp. **[live demo](https://eval.in/790411)**

```
<?php
$a = '01:04:06:02:55:28';
$b = '03:04:06:02:54:34';
$aTimestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('m:d:y:h:i:s', $a, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'))->getTimestamp();
$bTimestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('m:d:y:h:i:s', $b, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'))->getTimestamp();
echo date("m:d:y:h:i:s", ($aTimestamp + $bTimestamp)/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use timedelta objects if your format corresponds to a duration and not exact dates (see [live demo](https://eval.in/790525) or code below, assuming 1 year=365 days and 1 month=30 days). Notice that timedelta objects accept just days (rather than months or years, avoiding ambiguity). Timedelta objects allow arithmetic operations (see https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/datetime-timedelta.html)

Datetime objects assume a calendar, which means that they would use the actual duration of months and years between the two points (with months ranging 28-31 and maybe leap years instead of "standard" durations).

```
from datetime import timedelta
a = "01:04:06:02:55:28"
b = "03:04:06:02:54:34"

(y,mo,d,h,mi,s) = a.split(":");

tda = timedelta(days=int(y)*365+int(mo)*30+int(d), hours=int(h), minutes=int(mi), seconds=int(s));

(y,mo,d,h,mi,s) = b.split(":");

tdb = timedelta(days=int(y)*365+int(mo)*30+int(d), hours=int(h), minutes=int(mi), seconds=int(s));

print("a: " + str(tda))
print("b: " + str(tdb))
print("average: " + str((tda+tdb)/2))

# now we only need to format the output as needed
avgtd = (tda+tdb)/2
avgy = avgtd.days/365
avgm = (avgtd.days - avgy*365) / 30
avgd = (avgtd.days - avgy*365 - avgm*30)
avghou = avgtd.seconds / 3600
avgmin =  (avgtd.seconds - avghou*3600) / 60
avgsec =  (avgtd.seconds - avghou*3600 - avgmin*60)

print("average: " + str(avgtd))
print ("{}:{}:{}:{}:{}:{}".format(avgy,avgm,avgd,avghou,avgmin, avgsec))
```

Alternatively, you could just calculate the average of each field. But I think it would be strange having 0.5 years, 0 months, 0 days instead of having 0 years, 6 months. The code would be easier, though, if this is a valid option:

```
a = "01:04:06:02:55:28"
b = "03:04:06:02:54:34"

(ay,amo,ad,ah,ami,asec) = a.split(":");
(by,bmo,bd,bh,bmi,bsec) = b.split(":");
print ("{}:{}:{}:{}:{}:{}".format((int(ay)+int(by))/2.0,(int(amo)+int(bmo))/2.0,(int(ad)+int(bd))/2.0,(int(ah)+int(bh))/2.0,(int(ami)+int(bmi))/2.0,(int(asec)+int(bsec))/2.0))
```

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: Thanks airos for your effort, but it's not what i am looking for,                      
$a = '01:04:06:02:55:28';
$b = '03:04:06:02:54:34';                                                                     Iam expecting this kind of output                                                                            $c = (01+03)/2:(04+04)/2:(06+06)/2:(02+02)/2:(55+54)/2:(28+34)/2

Comment: You mean you need Y:M:D values and not only days, or you need float values for each field (if required) rather than adjusting the durations of smaller fields? With your approach, 0:0:0:0:0:0 and 1:0:0:0:0:0 would result into 0.5:0:0:0:0:0. Is this right ? Let me know and give me a second...

Comment: I am updating the answer

Comment: Can you check if this is what you meant?